# Holomorphic function is an homeomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis

I have got pretty confused with the following:

Assume $f$ is non-constant holomorphic function. Then there is a theorem that states that f is open. If in addition it is a bijection+onto, we get that this is precisely an homemorphism (i.e. the inverse is continous as well, since it is open).

However, if we look at $e^z:\{0 \le Imz < 2\pi\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, we have all the above, but this is not a homemorphism - we know that the inverse must be $log(z)$, which can not be defiened continously on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Your domain is not an open subset of the plane.

Comment: @user86418 so??

Comment: The theorem you quoted, about $f$ being an open map, has as a hypothesis that the domain of $f$ is an open set.

Comment: An open function is one which maps *open* sets to open sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $\{0 \leq \textrm{Im}(z) < 2\pi \}$ is not an open set.